# Java PDF creator as a Web Service vs Library

Tags: java, web-services, pdf

I want to use Java to create PDFs (as well as other documents) and I was thinking about using a web service to do so.  The source of data for these documents will reside in different places.  There will also be different callers to the service.

One of the callers/clients of the service requires a quick response time so I am debating on not using a web service here and instead just creating a separate library and use it's objects vs calling a web service.

The other callers/clients will not need a quick response, however there will be tons of requests from them, thus I am worried about that negatively impacting the caller/client which is dependent on a fast response.

Are my worries for the caller which needs a quick response time unfounded?  I would not be as concerned if there were not much data exchange, however if the service returns a PDF (or other document) I could see that possibly taking a while if the file is big.

The reason why I was hoping for a web service is to allow one place for code to live since there will be different callers.  I am open to the idea of just creating a library and having each calling application use the library if that would be a better approach.

Comment: If you link the lib, the app itself will be responsible for the PDF generation, which can be ok. If you want to provide a service, make sure it can satisfy all needs. If you can't don't do it then. Make the decision based on the client needs... But comparing a service to a program artifact does not seem to be appropriate for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have both?

Remember by creating a web service (rest for example) you just provide a http based interface for the service's own implementation. And what would that service implementation use? Right, your library.

So for time critical clients you ship the library and for the others you have your web service using the library but run on a dedicated server. This way you meet the timeliness for the few special clients while enjoying the other clients to use a centralized server running your service. Both worlds for almost one price.